# Is there a way to require/force use of a particular server WITHIN the query string (when running inside SSMS)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am aware that you can [use the GUI in SSMS](http://goo.gl/PZ3Ks) to specify which server to run against.

Is there a way of requesting a specific server, analogous to saying "***use ServerA.[DBName]***" from within the query script?

Answer (score 1):

**Pretty sure that this is not possible.** (like what we do to change the database name     `USE [db_name]`)

However there is a technique called `Linked Server` which allows you to connect to a second server inside your queries and use the resource on the second data source.

refer to this link for further information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

e.g.:

```
select foo.id 
from db1.table1 foo, 
     Server2.db_name.scheman_name.table_name bar 
where foo.name=bar.name
```

What is mentioned in the other answer (OpenDataSource) is :

> an ad hoc connection information as part of a four-part object name
>   without using a linked server name.

which is pretty much an implicit `Linked Server`

Answer (score 0):

Using [OpenDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) might be a way to set which server instance to access within the scope of a query - you may want to consult [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545364/tsql-command-to-connect-to-another-server-sql-server-2005) for more background/details.

Another option might be a `TRY..CATCH` block where the query verifies that it's being run on the correct server using [`SERVERPROPERTY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx), and throws an exception if it isn't - this lets you put a more human-readable error message out for the user.